# custom php function does not generate link after page refreshes

Tags: php

I have a layout where in one section I'm calling the file to load with a php function

```php
 //function to load content page
 function getPage($page) {
   Switch ($page) {
     case 'clients':
     include('clients/view.php');
     break;
   }
 }
```

when I'm viewing the view.php I have a dropdown menu that I have a link in depending on the $_GET['action'].  this is set up with another function.

```
function clientViewOptions($action) {

    if ($action == "") {

        echo '<a href="?page=clients&action=inactive"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle red"></i>Show Inactive</a>';
    } 

    if ($action == "inactive") {

        echo '<a href="?page=clients"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle green"></i>Show Active</a>';
    }

}
```

page loads, i'm able to open the drop down menu and I only have access to the "Show Inactive" link.   after I click that link, page loads, i open the drop down and I can see the icon/text for "Show Active" but it is not in the form of a link.

i have made sure that my $action for the function is capturing the right value and it is. I have also set a bare test link and that acts the same way, displays the test, but not in link form

--update--
the function is called in a hidden drop menu that is shown using js.  here is the area the function is called

```
    <div class="clientView animated bounceIn">

        <!-- drop menu heading -->
        <div class="dropMenuHead">
            -- Extra Options --
        </div>
        <!-- end heading -->
        <!-- links -->
        <div class="dropMenuBody">

            <!-- show options for type of client viewing -->
            <?php clientViewOptions($_GET["action"]);   ?>

        </div>
        <!-- end links -->

    </div>
    <!-- end drop menu -->
```

Comment: Please check the line `if ($action == "") {'. Conditions for both Active and Inactive are same.

Comment: I fixed it.  i accidentally erased the second condition when posting

Comment: Show where clientViewOptions is called.

Comment: ok, i've updated to show the section of code where it is called

Comment: Maybe some magic javascript code is rewriting divs with class dropMenuBody?

Comment: the only thing the javascript is for is to show and hide the drop menu.  it just changes the class based on user click

Comment: so i added an inactive client to the database and then tried it and now the link works.  but it only works if i have inactive clients.....guess i'll try to find that issue now.  thanks for making me keep trying things

Comment: using position absolute on the drop menu to take it out of the flow of the document is what causes the link to not be clickable when there is no data in the database.  weird....